# How can I install Ice SSB on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and would like to install Ice SSB that comes with Peppermint OS.

https://peppermintos.com/guide/ice/

https://github.com/peppermintos/ice

Is it possible to install this on Ubuntu? I don't see it in the repositories.

Comment: The GitHub repository you linked to is designed to build a package.  It's possible they expect you to use it only on Peppermint OS, and as such it's not built for Ubuntu directly.  You may have to build packages yourself.  Or, switch to Peppermint OS.  (However, the program and the guides were written explicitly for Peppermint, and may not apply properly or cleanly here on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

This utility is *not* built with Ubuntu in mind.  The GitHub repository you linked to is the core package data necessary to *build* the application and package, and it's entirely possible that this *could* be built for Ubuntu, however it is not part of core Ubuntu, and therefore not in the repositories.

---

The Original Poster of this question fond the following through research in a comment on this answer:

> Huh, turns out the Peppermint OS team already has a repository. https://launchpad.net/~peppermintos/+archive/ubuntu/release. And on a forum they said that they don't recommend installing ice using the PPA, they said to download the .deb and install it that way.

<sub>Since the answer is theirs, this answer is marked as Community Wiki, to avoid inaccurate rep gains.</sub>

Comment: Huh, turns out the Peppermint OS team already has a repository. https://launchpad.net/~peppermintos/+archive/ubuntu/release. And on a forum they said that they don't recommend installing ice using the ppa, they said to download the .deb and install it that way. Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody using *Debian* instead of Ubuntu its still pretty easy to install.  Since Debian does not allow/include *add-apt-repository* it takes a little more work to install Ice but in the end it should work exactly as it would for Peppermint or Ubuntu.

First add Peppermint's PPA: 

`sudo [your text editor like nano, gedit, pluma, etc] /etc/apt/sources.list.d/peppermint.list`

Then copy/paste the following, then save and exit:
 
*`# Peppermint 9 Repo
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peppermintos/p9-release/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/peppermintos/p9-respin/ubuntu bionic main`* 

Run this command to automatically add Peppermint's apt key:
  
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8407C49CC82B751AD961D657FD538AD29ED3B288`

Now you're going to be able to update your repos and install Ice all at once with this command:

**`sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ice`**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install ICE in Ubuntu 16.04 would be to simply download the current .deb from the Peppermint 8 PPA (the PPA linked above is old, and doesn't contain packages for xenial):
https://launchpad.net/~peppermintos/+archive/ubuntu/p8-release/+files/ice_5.2.8_all.deb
or the development version with some translations here:
https://launchpad.net/~peppermintos/+archive/ubuntu/ice-dev/+files/ice_5.3.0_all.deb

Comment: Why not just add the `ppa` and use regular package system to avoid problems? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peppermintos/p8-release`

Comment: Because as the ice package maintainer I can guarantee the current builds of ice in those PPA's won't break anything in Ubuntu 16.04 .. I cannot give that guarantee for future versions.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php?topic=5793.0

The links in the above comments are for download links to specific files that may or may not exist anymore. This link is to the peppermint forums where they provide a link to the most recent stable build and helpful information.